# can i bind a folder to a folder? - Subversion

Tags: svn, templates

Hello all if i have this folder path, can i "bind" a folder to the folder so?

```
|- main path
|-- theme
|--- domain1.com -> [customer template 1]
|--- domain2.com -> [customer template 2]
|--- domain3.com -> [customer template 3]
|- customer path
|-- customer template 1
|-- customer template 2
|-- customer temaplte 3
```

thanks for all help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look to [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals) which are like links but handled by Subversion and not by the OS.

Comment: Right now i have changes to Git, its much faster in Subversion its, :) but tanks for help all.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible using symbolic links (but it will work just fine only on filesystems that support symbolic links).

Just create a symlink as usual (`ln -s`), then add it and commit. Works like a charm. :)

If something goes wrong, check `svn:special`.

Comment: A note from svnbook (ch07s02): "Windows clients don't have symbolic links, and thus ignore any svn:special files coming from a repository that claim to be symbolic links. On Windows, the user ends up with an ordinary versioned file in the working copy."